# calling another ViewController on row selection in TableViewController

Tags: uitableview, call, segue, viewcontroller

I am using UITableViewController and on selection of row from the list i want to open another scene and send the info of the selected row. I got one link and i followed that and also i attched say Segue1 to segue2 in push mode. but when i am executing it is throwing error for no such segue associated with segue1.

below is the code for Row Selection:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"index is %ld",(long)indexPath.row );
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Put_Controller" sender:indexPath.self];



}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Put_Controller"]) 
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to set storyboard segue identifier:- Put_Controller
[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you checked that the name is set properly between the scenes?
[image]

Comment: which name you are talking about !! Please elaborate as i am checking as you are showing by arrow but i am not getting!! @Diego

Comment: the corrected image and was entered by Mayank Jain. Sorry if I put the picture storyboard segue

Answer (score 0):

Actually i was not setting the identifier in the attributes Inspector and that i got from the link attached and now its working ::http://prateekvjoshi.com/2013/11/02/how-to-trigger-a-segue-programmatically-in-ios/